# verifying Back end compatibility

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

It is possible to check the version of the android OS before installing the application?

I need to check the version of the mobile and customize the installation of the application based on the android versions.

Comment: the playstore filters it for you

Comment: Am a developer i need my app to find out the version of the mobile programmatically and it should customize it installations

Comment: Customize the installation _how_? Why can't you do whatever it is that you need to do the first time the app starts after installation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The Playstore filters already. For example you need a Camera then declare that you need that in your AndroidManifest.xml

If you need certain APIs which are only available on higher Version of Android you can for example use the Support Library for quite a lot of those things. Or you have to check the API Level at runtime and call Methods only when on those. There are Annotations for that also: @TargetApi() to help the IDE to check that you're calling the code correctly.

hth